# Can I install Terralith 2.0 to an existing Minecraft world?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-mods

I and my friend have an existing Minecraft world. We've only moved very little around the first starting block. Can we install Terralith 2.0 on the server and have it used in this existing Minecraft world for the newly generated blocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. But only the new chunks that will be generated will be affected by the mod. In alternative you can create a new world with the Terralith and then using World Edit or other similar mods to copy the piece of land from your old world and paste to the new generated one.